# SQL how to auto increment a value depending on another value

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, integer

I am creating a program where I am using a SQL Database, but I have a problem on how to solve the following problem.

I have a table named Warehouse where I have WarehouseID and a WarehouseName.

Then, I created another table named Aisle where I have WarehouseID (which should be the same field as before) and AisleID and AisleName.

So WarehouseID and AisleID can be 1, 2, 3... But what I want is that when I select WarehouseID = 1 to create a new AisleID, the database should be able to notice which is the last number of AisleID for WarehouseID = 1 and add an autoincrement.

So, can be multiple AisleID with the same value but only a WarehouseID with one unique value.

How can I do that in SQL?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(AisleID), 0) + 1
FROM Aisle
WHERE WarehouseID = 1
```

returns the new `AisleID` that you want to insert in the table `Aisle`.
But what value do you want for `AisleName`?
If `AisleName` is the same for all rows in `Aisle` with the same `WarehouseID` you could use `MAX(AisleName)`, or if it's not you must supply that value.

So you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO Aisle(AisleID, AisleName, WarehouseID)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(AisleID), 0) + 1, MAX(AisleName), ?
FROM Aisle
WHERE WarehouseID = ?
```

Replace `?` with the value of `WarehouseID` that you want the row to have.
Also replace `MAX(AisleName)` with the new value of `AisleName` if you want it to be different than the previous rows, or if it is the first row with that `WarehouseID`.